# Statusbar Changing color on react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have two three screens rendering home, profile and sell. 
Home and profile are fine, the IOSNavigator works and the background color remains the same(see img two, "Profile"), however when i switch to the sell screen it changes to white(see img one, "List Item")?

The code is exactly the same for all three screens just named differently and im not sure why it is doing this

```
const ProfileNavigator = () => (
  <NavigatorIOS
    initialRoute={{
      component: ProfileNavigator,
      title: 'Profile',
    }}
   style={{flex: 1}}
  />
);
```

Answer (score 0):

On the Profile screen(or just to prevent this from happening to all screens) try adding this to your render method:

```
<StatusBar
     barStyle="light-content"
 />
```

Sometimes the NavigatorIOS component has strange behaviours regarding to status bars

Comment: Thanks Marco, I have already tried this, it’s strange if I go into the react-dev tools and toggle some attribute on the navigation it will switch the white background to another screen ? Maybe just random behaviour from iOS side?

Comment: @tygar If you are using Expo try building it in native code by copying your project folder(or follow the steps in your root project folder, but you will not be able to go back to Expo) and run npm eject there to get the Xcode project created. Then build the app with Xcode on a device or simulator and check if it still has the same behaviour